# Cant call swap/v1/tokens

Tags: 0x

i can't call api swap/v1/tokens
I see "cross-origin" err.
so what should i do?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tokens endpoint is deprecated. Please see https://tokenlists.org/ for a better alternative.